# Asking Allah for the truth

Tags: allah, dream

Can I ask Allah to reveal me the truth about some matter, through a dream/vision or some other means? Since Allah is the One who knows and hears all things, I want to know if I can ask Him in my dua if He can reveal me the truth of a certain past situation?

Comment: You can ask Him anything you want. He will show/give you if He wills. What we can do is to wait for His decision. He does, when He wants to.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, this is not rational that Allah shows you a matter directly. It likewise is not easy that God shows you a matter through a dream or so on.
Of course it could be possible for you to reach your wish(or question) in some ways, Such as :

Consulting, actually take consult with informed people, thinking a lot regarding the matter, and perhaps another item could be Dua. Actually you can reach many of your issue through Dua and praying…

**I don’t know what precisely your issue is, but I reckon Istekharah   (الاستخاره)could be a good way for you to indicate the best path.**

in regard to how to do Istekharah (if you want to know), I found a site which could help you how to do that. (unfortunately this site is solely in Urdu and Farsi, so I hope you be familiar at least with one of the mentioned languages).

- [islamquest.net (Urdu)](http://islamquest.net/ur/archive/question/fa5113)
- [islamquest.net (Farsi (Persian))](http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa5113)

Answer (score 1):

Assalamu Alaikum, of course Allah is all hearer and knows all the mysteries. Indeed we can ask Him for solutions and answers, there is nothing wrong in it.

But definitely not in a dream or vision. Because how will you know that the dream/vision is true right from Allah. You might need the sense to understand this which no free-will bearing creations of Allah has.

The answer:

The best way is your imaan... Have faith in Allah, we Muslims have to submit our will to the Almighty.

Pray for your problems, ask Allah for the truth, notice the signs Allah shows you, the truth will insha Allah unfold by itself very soon. That is how it is recommended.

Allah might or might not answer for He knows what is best for us.

Istikaara is a way to ask the Almighty to show signs when people are in confusion. Like example which career path to choose. May be after knowing what is the truth you were looking for, you can do istikaara and make decision.

Don't look for dreams and visions, people make mistakes in the reality which we control, think about the dreams which we don't control, some causes of nightmares is even said to have jinns disturbing you at sleep.

Allah will show signs of truth... Trust Him and be patient. He will test the believers, times like this might easily encourage you to do a haram (like asking a sooth sayer) but there will be a thousand lies with one truth in them. Read Surah Al Isra.

> Surah Al Isra 17:81 ... And say, "Truth has come, and falsehood has departed. Indeed is falsehood, [by nature], ever bound to depart."

Answer (score 1):

Think of Us as children... I mean really young kids... who normally ask parents for things that many of which can be unreasonable or even harmful.. Allah knows what we are asking him for and why we ask for those things. It is for him to decide, for Him being the most knowledgeable, wise and understanding. He will decide whether to grant us what we ask him for. He will also decide how to give us what we asked him for on his way. The most important in all this is that we should trust his decisions and accept the way he runs things for us.

Answer (score 0):

Certainty is a rare thing in life itself, even rarer in dreams, most of them are not true or hard for us to make sense of. Perhaps there could be other ways for you to know what is right or wrong... Consultation, asking people, dua, or Istikhare as mentioned above, and insha'allah eventually you would come to truth and you would get your answer from where you didn't expect.
**Talaq: verse 3:** 
وَيَرْزُقْهُ مِنْ حَيْثُ لَا يَحْتَسِبُ وَمَن يَتَوَكَّلْ عَلَى اللَّهِ فَهُوَ حَسْبُهُ إِنَّ اللَّهَ بَالِغُ أَمْرِهِ قَدْ جَعَلَ اللَّهُ لِكُلِّ شَيْءٍ قَدْرًا .
And he provides for him from (sources) he never could imagine. And if any one puts his trust in Allah, sufficient is (Allah) for him. For Allah will surely accomplish his purpose: verily, for all things has Allah appointed a due proportion.

I think the best course would be to act casual on the matter until you come to a bulletproof piece of evidence.
**Sometimes it’s a test itself from God to see how you act based on what you are not certain of, I mean would you make a swift action or will you have the patience to wait till everything has prevailed itself and then act/judge/etc.**